# React button mailto on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React and Nextjs, and I was having issues with my contact button. I want it so when someone clicks on my button, it should open up their mail with my email prefilled (pretty much the mailto functionality).

`<Button onClick = {(href) => href - "mailto:email@yahoo.com"}> Email </Button>`

I can't seem to figure out why it won't work, on click the button doesn't do anything.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a `<a>` link instead of a button

Comment: I'd like it to be my styled button that is displayed and clicked

Comment: You can style `<a>` elements

Comment: Ahh I see, works great thanks!

Comment: Follow-up: Is there a way I can stretch the <a> tag to the entire length of the button? I want the mailto to activate if any part of the button is clicked

Comment: Wrap the button in the <a> tags

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, you could achieve the same thing with a tag. Even though it is already answered, I want to share my answer too, hope it helps others.

You can achieve the same result with a button too. In order to do that you will have to call `useRouter` hook from nextjs and then redirect user once they click on the button like so:

```
 import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => router.push('mailto:email@yahoo.com')}>
      Click me
    </button>
  )
}
```